# Is there a deadlock when acquiring, releasing, and then acquiring multiple permits with semaphores in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

The following code snippet is a solution to https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/ which runs `printFirst.run()`, `printSecond.run()`, and `printThird.run()` in order using a single semaphore. Three threads A, B, and C call the functions. Thread A will call `first`, thread B will call `second`, and thread C will call `third`.

I understand why `lock.acquire();` followed by `lock.release();` is required in `third`, rather than calling `lock.acquire(2);` immediately, due to the way Java assigns permits to waiting threads in a queue. Calling `lock.acquire(2);` creates a deadlock as nothing can ever release enough permits.

That being said, I do not understand how `lock.acquire();` followed by `lock.release();` before this fixes it.

Would somebody be able to explain to me what happens in the situation where `first` first calls `lock.release()` and then `third` calls `lock.acquire(); lock.release(); lock.acquire(2);` before `second` runs? Does this result in a deadlock, in the same way that calling `lock.acquire(2);` by itself would result in a deadlock? Is this just an unlikely situation which is why this works?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
class Foo {
    
    private Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(0);

    public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {
        // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        printFirst.run();
        lock.release();
    }

    public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.acquire();
        // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
        printSecond.run();
        lock.release(2);
    }

    public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.acquire();
        lock.release();
        lock.acquire(2);
        // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
        printThird.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now understand why this is correct and will not deadlock.

Having the `acquire()` and `release()` before `acquire(2)` in `third()` means that the number of permits is guaranteed to either be 1 at the time it acquires, meaning that `second()` can acquire and still progress, OR `second()` has already called `acquire()` and there are 0 permits, but this doesn't matter because `second()` is about to `release(2)`, which will allow `third()` to continue.

Without `acquire()` and `release()` in `third()`, there is a chance `third()` will `acquire(2)` before ANY progress has been made in the other threads (i.e. there are no permits and `second()` hasn't successfully acquired), meaning that the released permit in `first()` will go towards `third()` and second's acquire will never succeed.